# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No such column: id

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, nativequery

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No such column: id
```

When table already contains the column `id`

I'm trying to have the following native SQL query that runs with expected results from within MariaDB SQL from a Repository class:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.table2_id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2.column1_number = 1 AND
        t2.id IS NOT NULL
  )
ORDER BY t1.name
```

The entity classes are as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Table1 {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer number;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "table2_id")
    private Table2 table2;

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="table2")
public class Table2 {
    private  Integer id;
    private  Integer column1_number;

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

   // Getters and Setters
}
```

The Repository is:

```java
@Repository
public interface Table1Repository extends JpaRepository<Table1, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT name FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.table2_id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.column1_number = ?1 AND t2.id IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY t1.name", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Table1> findByNumberOrderByName(Integer number);
}
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error at run time? This error does not occur at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT name FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.table2_id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.column1_number = ?1 AND t2.id IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY t1.name", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Table1> findByNumberOrderByName(Integer number);
```

should have been `List<String>` and not `List<Table1>`

and so the solution was:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT name FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.table2_id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.column1_number = ?1 AND t2.id IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY t1.name", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> findByNumberOrderByName(Integer number);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search in table2 using id, but you didn't choose the correct mapping column from table1 which should be **table2_id.id** , so the query should be something like this

```sql
SELECT name FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.table2_id.id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.column1_number = 1 AND t2.id IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY t1.name
```

Also note *you're using native query*, that means querying the db directly, so make sure you're using the same correct name in your database tables.

Comment: I want to do a native query. For example if I had no parameters and made the query use `1` instead of `?1`  in the JPQL query string value why does it still give the same error message? Why is the `id` column giving no such column still in that case? It's pure native. Do I need to reference where the `id` column comes from?

Comment: Of course, as I mentioned native meaning querying DB directly so everything must be clear to the DB engine.

Comment: I also noticed you’re expecting List<Object> , this should be List<String>.

Comment: Thank you; however, I have already found an answer. I have the submitted answer located here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56088402/11003540 where I have already addressed this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Id element to table1 and annotated both tables Id fields with @Id annotation like below.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```